# Adding seconds to ISO 8601 datestamp string

Tags: python, json, iso8601, datestamp

I am trying to add seconds to a datestamp string that is received from a json object but the datetime function I am trying to use does not allow strings and wants the date to be separated like: `datetime.strftime(2011,11,18)`. Here is what I have:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def call():
    pay = {'token' : "802ba928cd3ce9acd90595df2853ee2b"}
    r = requests.post('http://challenge.code2040.org/api/dating',
                      params=pay)
    response = r.json()
    time = response['datestamp']
    interval = response['interval']
    utc = datetime.strftime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT&H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    timestamp = (utc-time).total_seconds()
    utc_dt = datetime(time) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)
    print(utc_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```

Is there another way I can add time to a ISO8601 datestamp?

Comment: I think you want `datetime.strptime` to convert the string into a datetime object that you can add to

Comment: Further, you can get the ISO format of a datetime object by `some_datetime.isoformat()`

Comment: There is some discussion on this post about parsing ISO8601. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python?rq=1

Comment: What's the purpose of subtracting `utc` and `time` variables? Aren't they both the same value?